# SAS - Macro CRLF line terminator and space character

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to run the below macro. Which should create a new file taking some data from the original file and create a new file in the right format. This file will be exported as a delimited file with a CRLF line terminator record.

```
%Macro Createfile(inputfile,Outputfile,Item_code, Code, Value,Comment);
      Data &Outputfile (Keep = Item_Code Code Value Comment); 
                        Retain Item_Code Code Value Comment;set &inputfile;
          set &inputfile;
          Item_code = &Item_code;
          Code = &Code;
          Value =&Value;    
          Comment = &Comment
     run; 
%mend Createfile;
```

If I now run it works fine for all of the files it needs to generate. however when I provide the below inputs

```
&Createfile(file1,file2,Item,""," ",Comment_txt);
```

with file1 & file2 being the 2 input file and output file. Item and comment_txt being 2 fields from file1 and "", " " being variables.

However for this case the export for one reason or another does not contain the CRLF line terminator as well as the space is not being exported while this is needed. Therefore I wanted to see how to error proof this to ensure this is included as it is the case for the other files generated from the same inputfile.

Comment: The macro you posted just creates a dataset, it doesn't output it.  The output step would be the one you'd want to post here I imagine.  Also note that `' '` and `''` are identical in SAS, except in a few very very specific and temporary situations.

Comment: `PROC EXPORT DATA =file2 OUTFILE = "&outfile" REPLACE DBMS = DLM; DELIMITER = '|'; PUTNAMES = NO; RUN;` I use this proc export to generate my output file. if ' ' and '' are identical how could we then ensure their would be a space between the delimiters?